# How can I easily add a batch of files to the HandBrake queue?

Tags: macos, encoding

How do I add multiple files into the queue at once in [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)?

I heard that multiple files can be added to the queue by selecting the folder. But when I select the folder as source, only the first file is added, rather than all the files.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this guide help you in isolating a step that gives you an error so we can help further? http://www.osomac.com/apps/osx/handbrake-batch/

Answer (score 63):

After adding the folder as the source, File>Add All Titles To Queue

Comment: I can't get the settings to apply to all the files. I select add all titles to queue, then it asks if I want to use the current settings, I click yes, but the settings seem to be reset.

Comment: @Harry I think you need to save the current settings as a preset.

Comment: It's not correct. File>Add Titles To Queue...>Check all titles you want>Add. Also you probably need to go to Preferences>General>Output Files>"Turn on Automatically name output files"

Comment: The key is that you need to select the FOLDER as your source, THEN add files, which is really counter-intuitive.  Should be one or the other, not both.

Comment: What's worked for me (at least on Debian) is Open Source, select a folder containing all the files I want to work on, and then after it finishes processing them, Queue -> Add Multiple, and from there, it uses the loaded preset/settings, and each one I check in the modal, it will add to the Queue once I click "Finish"

Answer (score 5):

I've wondered about automating HandBrake using the command line interface (CLI) and Automator. Here's a tutorial that covers lots of details of using the CLI, though I think it only processes one file at a time, rather than building a queue:
http://www.mactalk.com.au/18/87490-guide-convert-movies-ipod-format-one-click-finder.html

While looking for a solution to answer this question, I came upon a thread about using Hazel (instead of Automator - not free):
http://www.noodlesoft.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=859&p=3356#p3356

For the amount of labor I go through when converting videos, I'm considering giving this a try since it can help with other tasks such as copying to iTunes and my NAS.

For reference, here's a link to HandBrake's CLI Guide:
https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide

Answer (score 4):

[Here's](https://github.com/paulgrav/Handbrake-Automator-Action/downloads) your answer. It's a Handbrake add-on for Automator.

Download the most recent zip, open it, double-click on the automator action to add the Handbrake action to Automator.

Answer (score 4):

If you want more control over the HandBrake/Automator integration, I wrote a blog post covering a custom Service I made with Automator that uses AppleScript to talk to the CLI.

http://dovfrankel.com/post/37269517618/using-handbrake-on-a-list-of-files

Comment: Hi can you modify your script to include subtitles please?

Comment: @Harry I can't think of a good general-purpose way to add subtitles, which would work for everybody. If you'd like more information to add it to the `AppleScript` it runs, this link should help: https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide#SubtitleOptions  That way, you will get your subtitles exactly how you like them.

Comment: @Harry this tool is incredible. I shall pour over it to learn. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The Mac OS version has no explicit "open folder" option, however, you can still open a folder and process the content in batch mode.

Click the button "Open Source" and...
if you are inside the folder you want to process, "do not select any file", just click the open button.

OR

Select the folder to process and then click open.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to set up multiple files for processing is to use the '[Add to Queue](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/Queue)' button (or the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> shortcut) in Handbrake.

This is by design as Handbrake requires you specify a destination folder and file name for the converted video file. If you were able to add all files in a folder, how would Handbrake know the unique output location and name for each rendered file? It doesn't make any guesses about those things, it requires the user to specify them for each render.

Once you've staged each file in the queue you can use the Start button (or the <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> shortcut) to tell Handbrake to begin processing the queue.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your answer, but come on, `If you were able to add all files in a folder, how would Handbrake know the unique output location and name for each rendered file?` Same location as the previous file? Don't change the name? Lol.

Comment: @Harry you'll have to take that up with the Handbrake developers. They've written in no logic to guess an output file name. You'll notice that's the case when you load new input files, output stays the same. I didn't write it, so your complaints are lost on me.

Comment: Actually, it ALWAYS guesses an output name when selecting a source file. It is the same as the original file name with a new suffix.

Comment: @andreas yes, it's been improved since this question and answer were written.